# How to deploy WinForms referenced assemblies that contain folders in their output

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, deployment

I have a Winforms project A, that references a class library assembly B. Assembly B has folders containing files that are set to **Build Action = None** and **Copy to Output Directory = True**. These folders and files are correctly output to the bin folder of assembly B. They are not referenced files, merely ones I need to load at run-time from the deployed location.

When running project A, code in assembly B needs to access the folders and files described.  **AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory** will give me the running location of project A, but the folders and files do not exist at that location. How do I locate these files in C# code from assembly B?

Assembly B gets compiled into various solution types (winforms, web services, etc), so I need a deployment that will work in all scenarios.

I hope that makes sense! I guess I'm looking for a) a change to the way it gets to deployed so that the folders and files are also in the running directory, or b) a change to the code in assembly B.

I would be grateful for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If Assembly B is going to be shipped and used outside the application, I suggest making the folders embedded resources instead of external folders on disk. This of course requires a code change whereever these files are used in the application, to get them from ResourceStreams rather than files on disk.

If the folders are just data that needs to be accessed by the Application when you run it, then the easiest solution is to build both projects to a common output directory. Set the output directory from e.g.

```
   bin\Debug
```

to

```
   ..\bin\Debug
```

This way the output of both A and B, including the folders, will be in the same directory (if the projects are in folders under the solution directory as is normal). This can also help speed up your build.

Comment: I don't think I can make them embedded resources because there are files with the same names in multiple folders. But correct me if I'm wrong there?

Comment: As for a common output folder, the code for each assembly lives in completely separate areas, so I'd probably have to hard code a full path somewhere wouldn't I?

Comment: Q1: You can have a folder structure for embedded resources. 
Q2: You mean the projects are not part of the same solution?

Comment: I was wrong about the embedded resource names: the separate folders give me different namespaces. So I'll be using this method I think. Thanks Anders!

Comment: Commented at the same time. Q2: the projects are part of the same solution, but the code for each project is in completely different locations. B was added to the main solution for A, but lives in another folder, if that makes sense.

Comment: The embedded resources route is working exactly as I need it - thanks Anders!

Answer (score 1):

You can add post-build event through project properties. In this event you can run command to copy the assembly and the folders and its contents to appropriate location.

In your code if you need the location of the loaded assembly then you can use Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase

Comment: Thanks Jack, that would probably achieve what I want, although the copy command would need to be conditional upon which parent solution was being compiled because of the different output locations. I've got it working nicely with Anders' embedded resources now.